# make comma separated strings from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I have JavaScript multidimensional array like this:

```
a   1
b   2
c   3
```

I want it converted into comma separated value like this:

```
function reg() {
    var result = [];
    var comma_value;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrc.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(arrc[i].value)) {
            result.push([arrp[i].value, arrc[i].value]);
        }

        // result is an array 
        // My desired result:
        // comma_value = "a,1;b,2;c,3"
    }

    $('#str').val(JSON.stringify(result));

    console.table(result);
    console.log(result.join(', '));
}
```

Comment: [MDN Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?v=example)

Comment: Can you clarify the multidimensional array structure? Your 'like this' is pretty hard to understand.

Comment: i tried but its not working correctly

Comment: it's two dimensional  array

Comment: result.push( [ a,1 ] );
result.push( [ b,2 ] );
result.push( [ c,3 ] );

Comment: What is your definition of "two dimensional array"? I see two one-dimensional arrays in your code: `arrp` and `arrc`, both containing objects with a `value` property. I don't understand your `a 1, b 2, c 3`.

Comment: result.push( [ a,1 ] );
    result.push( [ b,2 ] );
    result.push( [ c,3 ] );

Comment: @le_m i merge two arrays value into one array (result)

Comment: So your input array is actually `array = [
  ['a', 1],
  ['b', 2],
  ['c', 3]
]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your comments I assume you are simply looking for [`Array.prototype.join(';')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
let array = [
  ['a', 1],
  ['b', 2],
  ['c', 3]
];

let comma_value = array.join(';');

console.log(comma_value); // 'a,1;b,2;c,3'
```

This works due to the implicit array element `['a', 1]` to string `'a,1'` conversion performed within the `array.join(';')` method call.

If you are curious *how* this works: When you call `array.join(';')`, the individual array elements are first converted to strings via the `Array.prototype.toString()` method:

```
['a', 1].toString() // returns 'a,1'
```

Subsequently, those strings are joined with the `';'` separator in between.

However, I don't see how this and your comments relate to the given `reg()` function. That code features two one-dimensional arrays with `{value: ...}` objects as elements.

Comment: actually not `join` is used, but rather `toString` is used to get a primitive value of an array for the inner arrays. it looks like `join`, but it is `toString`.

Comment: @NinaScholz You are right, but this is all happening within the `array.join(';')` method call. I am not sure if OP is interested in *how* this element to string conversion happens within that method call. I clarified the answer a little bit.

Comment: i would be interested ... ;-)

Comment: @NinaScholz Ok ok, I included it - you are a better teacher than I am ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
alert( [["a",1],["b",2]].map(e=>e.join()).join(";"));
```

Join the inner Arrays, then the outer...